# Ошибка errno2 при установке пакета с помощью pip

Tags: python, python-3.5, pip, package, install

Помогите исправить ошибку. При установке пакета с помощью pip, возвращается ошибка

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No
>   such file or directory: 'E:\MyModules\dist\vsearch-1.0.tar'

Использую

```
py -3 -m pip install vsearch-1.0.tar
```

Проверил имя архива. Имя введено правильно. Текущий рабочий каталог указан правильно. В чем еще может быть причина такой ошибки не пойму. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Формата `.tar` вроде нет в поддерживаемых. Скорее всего, формат файла `.tar.gz`, но поскольку Windows скрывает расширение файла по дефолту, файл показывается как `.tar`. Попробуй `py -3 -m pip install vsearch-1.0.tar.gz` (добавил `.gz` в конце).

Comment: А, или ещё может быть формат `.tar.bz2`, он тоже поддерживается - если не сработает `.gz`, попрбуй с `.bz2`. Ну и общий совет - отключить скрывание расширений файлов в проводнике.

Comment: Спасибо, совет помог.